# Where to learn about Trusts and alike?

Tags: mutual-funds, trusts, bond-funds, equity, hedge-funds

Sadly I have already gone down the Computer Science route for a degree, however I would like to learn more about Trusts, Funds, Equities etc... for a future career or for personal investments.

I have spent quite a lot of time researching from various sources, learning difference between open ended and closed ended, among other things. I was confident enough to put £500 into a high risk investment Fund with JP Morgan due to the past returns and the rating from Morning Star, so far everything seems to be going well. I know past performance does not mean future performance will be same, you can get back less than you invested. I am not completely new to this, nor am I immature.

My questions:

1)

> How do I calculate my returns on say a £500 investment with this
>   Trust? 
>   http://am.jpmorgan.co.uk/investment-trusts/trusts/elect-managed-income-jpm-it.aspx?isin=GB0034080217
>
> I assume it is the Net Asset Value (NAV). So forgetting fees, it
>   would be calculated like this for 12/13:
>
> 500 + 21.24% = £606.20

2)

> Where can I learn more about this so I can stop asking these
>   beginner questions in the future? Be nice if I was given a list of
>   resources, from beginner for fun investor and above.

I have shown this to a lot of friends that are annoyed with their poor interest from savings accounts. They admire me for not being a sheep and researching this before putting £500 into a tax free ISA stocks and shares. We all wish to work together to learn more about this to do more with our money. Thanks!

Comment: Don't be sad that you went down a computer science path; I did too and now I look after large investment bank's accounts with our company.

Answer (score 3):

An investment trust is quoted just like a share. You just compare what you paid (your book cost) with its current share price, not the NAV, as a trust's price can be at a premium greater than the actual share price or a discount.

Comment: What about when I am buying the Trust, what dot they use to determine what my £500 is worth, the Share Price?

Comment: @k1308517 its the share price at the time you put the order in just like a normal share.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to specifically address your second question. There are a number of great resources available online, but I found that when I was first starting out the website [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/) was a very helpful resource.

There you will find a wide range of information regarding investing, investment vehicles, and glossaries of key terms with robust definitions to help you with the financial jargon.